# $http success callback is called when an error arrived

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using AnguarJS $http service to call my server API on an Ionic app.

I am using a code similar to this :

```
$http({ 
   method: 'POST',
   url: "url"
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  ... handle success operations
}, function errorCallback(error) {
  ... handle error.
}
```

all seems to work perfectly well. when the API is called successfully, the successCallback function is called.

However, when an error like 500 arrived, I am also getting it in the success callback.

I would consider errors to arrive to the errorCallback.

Comment: is there more to the promise chain than shown and if so are you returning anything in the `errorCallback`? Not enough shown for us to reproduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have any http response interceptor (e.g: using `$httpProvider.responseInterceptors`) setup in your application?

[There was a user hitting a very similar issue in GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4419) whose issue was an interceptor that didn't reject rejections.

Other users pointed him to this nice GitHub Gist showcasing how to correctly implement a response interceptor: https://gist.github.com/gnomeontherun/5678505.

Comment: Seems like the problem we have :) Thanks !